# visual studio в virtual box

Tags: c++, c, winapi, virtualbox

Здравствуйте, у меня такая проблема. Поставил на виртуалке windows7, в виртуалке задал настройку com1 порт ассоциировать как файл 1.txt (там можно было это сделать)  в моей убунте. В visual studio 2015 написал прогу:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
HANDLE h;
h = CreateFile(L"COM1", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
cout « "OkOpen" « endl;
}
else
{
cout « "Bad" « endl;
getchar();
return 0;
}
char buf[25];
memset(buf, 0, 25);
strcpy(buf, "hell is my name");
DWORD wtn;
OVERLAPPED ol;
WriteFile(h, buf, 25, &wtn, &ol);
cout « wtn « endl;
FlushFileBuffers(h);
CloseHandle(h);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Но он не пишет в файл 1.txt ничего. В чем может быть проблема, при этом прога выдала OkOpen
Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема номер раз - Вы не проверяете результат возвращаемый функцией `WriteFile()`. В случае ошибки она вернет `false`, а `GetLastError()` вернет код самой ошибки.

Далее, Вы зачем-то передаете указатель на структуру `OVERLAPPED`, хотя файл создаете без флага `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` и никаких намеков на то, что Вы хотите работать с файлом асинхронно нет. При этом в самой структуре передаете мусор.

Итого, код должен быть таким

```
if (!WriteFile(h, buf, 25, &wtn, NULL))
  cout << "Error writee file. Code: " << GetLastError() << endl;
```

Comment: Проверил, запись произошла. Можно закрывать вопрос: ошибка была в том, что не настроил параметры передачи через com-порт. Помогла статья http://blablacode.ru/programmirovanie/392